# Creating an empty table, with fixed columns - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm very new to ruby on rails, been trying to play around with it in the past few days.
Basically trying to: Create a empty table, with fixed columns - Ruby on Rails

I've created a model like so:

```
rails g model table
rails g migration table
```

my tables.rb files looks like this:

```
class Tables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :table, :firstname, :string
    add_column :table, :lastname, :string
  end
end
```

(hopefully I created the columns okay)

I then run:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

but seem to get an error no such table: table (but I thought I created it ? )

Also what is a good view I can use to see my table on localhost:3000, in a html.erb file?

Comment: check this tutorial out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: As an aside, using generic terms such as "table" is not a good practice, especially if they are keywords.  It is much better to use a business-function oriented descriptive name such as User.  Also, make sure table names are always singular, not plural, just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are displaying as your tables.rb file is a migration file, not a model.  Models are stored in app/models.  Migrations are in db/migrate and have a name that is a datetime stamp followed by the migration name.

Your migration is performing add_column.  You can't add_column until you create_table.  That migration should have been built using "rails g model table".  Please show all migrations with the entire filename.

Check the document that dax provided.  The rails generate command uses a stylized command line.  Many standard migration functions, such as creating tables and adding columns, can be automatically generated by using the correct migration name.  For example:

```
rails g migration add_url_to_feed url:string
```

This will create a migration that adds a string column called url to the feed table.

Generally, migrations should do what you need.  However there is another command, rake, that you will need.  The reference is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html).  For example:

```
rake db:create          # Create the database from config/database.yml for the current Rails.env
```

can create the database for you.

Comment: How would i add a column, after I already generated model and called rake ?

Comment: The add_column migration would do that, certainly.  The recommendation on the migration name is for ease of use.